# Бинарный поиск в массиве. Питон

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ребят, обязательно искать средний элемент как:

```
low=0
high=len(array)-1
mid=(low+high)/2
```

Зачем нужно прибавлять low, все равно с нулевого индекса начинаем искать? Нельзя просто:

```
mid=high/2?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

На первой итерации - можно. Но если не писать отдельный код для первой итерации поиска - нельзя.